# Slow segues to pages with imagepickers?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I've had this as a common problem throughout most of my apps. I don't normally use Navigation Controllers, maybe this is where the fault is, but if I have a button that triggers a push segue to a View Controller with UIImagePickers the load times are always unusually long. I've tried presenting the view with the other segue options and the problem persists.

There's nothing else on the page that should be causing this. I've got a few text fields, but the view controller handles:

```
class CreateAccountVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate , UITextFieldDelegate{
```

What's the cause/solution to this? None of my other pages have this lag time so it's not the simulator, and loading to this page can take up to 4-5 seconds.

Comment: What happens if you perform the segue on the main thread?

Comment: @Sam Yeah same issue. Set up an IBAction and in dispatchqueue.main.async I called the segue versus just doing it through the storyboard and it was the same.

Comment: ok could you show part of your code that present the UIImagePickerController ?